# Modificar paginá com JS para criar link

Tags: javascript

Preciso modificar uma pagina para que ela ofereça um link para um executar um video em um play externo...

O meu atual script:

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';

   var tag = document.querySelector("video source").src;
   //location.href=tag;
   //window.locationf=tag;
   document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML = "<a href='' id='link'>Assita o EP via Player Externo</a>";
   document.querySelector("script").src = "a";
})();
```

Está é a pagina que quero modificar: http://showpl.tk/a9809

- O script precisa pegar o link src da TAG "video"...

  //var tag = document.querySelector("video source").src;
- O script tem que remover o  da pagina...

  //document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML = "Assita o EP via Player Externo";
- O script tem que usar o valor da variavel TAG no campo HREF do link com ID=LINK...

  //Não sei como modificar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você já possui a `url`, você apenas deve colocar ela dentro de `href` da tag `a` :

```
var a = "<a href='" + tag + "' id='link'>Assita o EP via Player Externo</a>";
document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML = a;
```

Comment: Funcionou... Obrigado